# Safety-critical software and optimising compilers

Tags: c, standards, embedded-systems

I'm reading some internal documentation for code developed to the [MISRA C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MISRA_C) guidelines, and I see that in compiler flags section of the documentation there is a note to compile with optimisation off (`-O0`). I'm new to safety-critical development, so in my mind turning off optimisation is overly-pessimistic and modern compilers will produce valid code with moderate optimisation, and anyway a decent test suite will catch compiler flaws.

Are there good arguments for disabling optimisation? Perhaps because of this disabling, the code is riddled with left- and right-shifts replacing divisions and other micro-optimisations that I believe we should leave to the compiler to deal with.

Comment: What is your application? My answer mostly relates to commercial aerospace, which often uses MISRA as a coding standard.

Comment: `I'm new to safety-critical development, so in my mind turning off optimisation is overly-pessimistic and modern compilers will produce valid code with moderate optimisation, and anyway a decent test suite will catch compiler flaws.` Testing can't prove the absence of bugs, and safety can't be left to chance. Unless there's *proof* the optimizations are actually correct, it makes sense to avoid them.

Comment: One question you should be asking is whether or not the object code actually needs to be optimized.  If it runs acceptably with the optimization turned off, then there's no reason to turn it on.  Lots of compilers have thorough test suites, and we still find bugs in them.

Comment: The product is vehicle camera-related, and the code does need to be optimised, as it is one of the objectives we have.

Comment: @KenY-N can you clarify what you mean by "the code does need to be optimised"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I agree with you that it's overly pessimistic, but some (potentially historical) reasons:

- [DO-178C Level A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DO-178C#Software_level) code requires **Source Code to Object Code Traceability**, which is much harder to prove manually with optimized code (and qualified compilers are very expensive)
- optimised code is harder to debug, which might prohibit scripted debugging opportunities
- there *could* be more compiler bugs during optimization

Comment: Regarding third point: in the last couple of years alone I already filed a couple of optimization bugs to compiler vendors, and that's just me. Searching for 'gcc optimization bug' etc also reveals the problem is most definitely real.

Comment: Also, consider the real cost of not optimising the code is a bit extra on the hardware budget.  It's just not worth the additional risk to save a few bucks on hardware.

Answer (score 4):

It's not just compiler *bugs* you have to worry about. Some "perfectly valid" (ie. conforming to the letter of the language spec) compiler optimizations produce quite unexpected behavior. See [Finding Undefined Behavior Bugs by Finding Dead Code](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/970).

> The point is that these problems are real, and they’re nasty because the problem can only be seen by looking at the compiler’s output. Compilers are getting smarter all the time, causing code that previously worked to break. A sufficiently advanced compiler is indistinguishable from an adversary.

Comment: Arguably the problem there is that the code has undefined behavior. Although the optimizations can produce surprising results in those cases, such code is unacceptable for safety-critical applications even if they're turned off.

Comment: But sometimes the "optimization" makes the effect of your undefined behavior much worse. And other times you know exactly what the behavior should be, only the compiler is taking advantage of the spec saying it should be "undefined" to do bad things. (because *any* behavior doesn't contradict a part of the spec that says "undefined"). Eg. assuming arithmetic doesn't wrap even on architectures where it does (and the programmer knows it does and relies on it): http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/162289

Comment: And see here for some heated discussion of this issue in gcc: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=30475 In the end it was "RESOLVED INVALID" so it's not getting fixed!

Comment: `Eg. assuming arithmetic doesn't wrap even on architectures where it does (and the programmer knows it does and relies on it)`. It doesn't matter that the hardware supports signed arithmetic overflow. You're writing C, not assembly, so the only behavior that counts is what the C standard says. Even if the compiler guarantees that a particular undefined behavior will be handled a certain way, you're going to have trouble if you ever switch compilers. More importantly you're going to get warnings from static analysis tools (which you *should* be using) and you're going to start ignoring them.

Comment: An interesting, yet moot answer. Simply don't rely on UB. End of story. Still scared of UB? Simply don't use a language with UB. End of story.

Comment: @ThomasEding: I'm sure the same people also decry unspecified behavor the same way.

Comment: The GCC developers still do not understand that there's a massive difference between "technically allowed according to a literal reading of the C specs" and "sane in practice". The issue with GCC and signed integer overflow is that the C specs are bad (signed integer overflow should've been implementation defined from the beginning, and most implementations should've done wrapping to mirror the behaviour for unsigned integers and/or the target machine). "Undefined (by the spec) behaviour" does not exclude "defined by the implementation as wrapping".

Comment: @Brendan: None of the existing categories of behavior are really appropriate for things like integer overflow.  What's really needed is a means via which programs can indicate their requirements, and compilers can either honor such requirements or reject programs that demand them.  If integer overflow were to signal in Implementation-Defined fashion, for example, a compiler given a program performed the same integer computation on every pass through a loop would be unable to hoist the computation unless it could ensure that overflow wouldn't raise the signal until the proper time.

Comment: @Brendan: For many programs, raising the signal early would be just fine, but having an integer overflow raise a signals at an unspecified times before they occur goes a bit beyond how "Implementation-defined behavior" is expected to work.  What I find absurd is that for most forms of UB, most programs don't really need *precise* action, but could give compilers lots of room to optimize. Many programs would benefit, for example, from a model where compilers may at their convenience perform signed computations on types larger than specified, truncating excess bits when values are exposed to...

Comment: ...outside code.  That would thus allow a compiler to evaluate `x+1 > y` as `x>=y`, but also allow programmers to write `x+1 > y` in cases where evaluation as `(int)(x+1u) > y` or `x+1LL > y` would be equally acceptable, rather than having to pick one of the above in cases where the other could have been more efficient.

Comment: @Doval: The authors of the C Standard have explicitly said "Although it strove to give programmers the opportunity to write truly portable programs, the C89 Committee did not want to force programmers into writing portably, to preclude the use of C as a “high-level assembler”: the ability to write machine-specific code is one of the strengths of C."  While the Standard doesn't require implementations to be usable as high-level assemblers, the notion that people who use it for such purpose are somehow "abusing" it is directly contradicted by the authors of the Standard.

Answer (score 2):

If the optimiser for your chipset/platform is not known to be reliable, then you need to ask yourself what would be the side effect of incorrect code being deployed to your embedded device:

- A Set Top Box may crash and need the user to restart.
- A hospital life-support system, might cause loss of life.

While comprehensive system tests will help to catch known scenarios, it's the unknown scenarios that will likely catch you out.

Given this, it seems like there may be some premature optimisation going on in the code base - have you performance-profiled the code to determine that code with all the shift operators is the primary cause of performance problems? Are you using the best algorithm for the job?

Comment: The compiler we seem to be using (I haven't got a copy yet!) is an EOLed tool, so I suppose its optimisation won't be up to the gcc or clang, etc, level. I mentioned the shifts just because they stand out in the code, and expressions like `lUL << 5UL` (yes, that is real code!) make me double-take.